# String Extraction and Insertion Functions in C?

Tags: c, string, file, malloc, free

I need to write these two functions:

Precondition: hMy_string is the handle to a valid My_string object.
Postcondition: hMy_string will be the handle of a string object that contains
the next string from the file stream fp according to the following rules.

1) Leading whitespace will be ignored.

2) All characters (after the first non-whitespace character is obtained and included) will be added to the string until a stopping condition
is met. The capacity of the string will continue to grow as needed
until all characters are stored.

3) A stopping condition is met if we read a whitespace character after
we have read at least one non-whitespace character or if we reach
the end of the file.
Function will return SUCCESS if a non-empty string is read successfully.
and failure otherwise. Remember that the incoming string may aleady
contain some data and this function should replace the data but not
necessarily resize the array unless needed.

```
Status my_string_extraction(MY_STRING hMy_string, FILE* fp);
```

Precondition: hMy_string is the handle to a valid My_string object.

Postcondition: Writes the characters contained in the string object indicated by the handle hMy_string to the file stream fp.
Function will return SUCCESS if it successfully writes the string and
FAILURE otherwise.

```
Status my_string_insertion(MY_STRING hMy_string, FILE* fp);
```

However, I am getting a segmentation fault with my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "my_string.h"

Status my_string_extraction(MY_STRING hMy_string, FILE *fp)
{
    string *pString = (string *) hMy_string;
    int lws = 0;
    int exit = 0;
    int nws = 0;
    int i;
    int count = 0;

    while(fp != NULL && exit == 0) {
        if(pString->size >= pString->capacity) {
            char *t_data = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * pString->capacity * 2);
            if(t_data == NULL) {
                return FAILURE;
            }

            for(i = 0; i < pString->size; i++) {
                t_data[i] = pString->data[i];
            }

            free(pString->data);
            pString->data = t_data;
            pString->capacity *= 2;

            if(getc(fp) == ' ' && lws == 0) {
                lws++;
            } else if(getc(fp) == ' ' && lws == 1) {
                exit++;
            } else if(getc(fp) == ' ' && nws > 0) {
                exit++;
            } else {
                pString->data[count] = getc(fp);
                count++;
                pString->size++;
                nws++;
            }

            fp++;
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    Status my_string_insertion(MY_STRING hMy_string, FILE *fp)
    {
        int i;
        string *pString = (string *) hMy_string;

        for(i = 0; i < pString->size; i++) {
            putc(pString->data[i], fp);
        }

        if(fp == NULL) {
            return FAILURE;
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: what is MY_STRING? where is the header?

Comment: What is the input you're using when you get the crash? What line is the crash on?

Comment: MY_STRING just means void * in this case. Not sure how to see which line the crash occurs.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

> I am getting a segmentation fault with my current code

Why do you do this:

```
  fp++;   // incrementing pointer does not get you the next character in the file
```

When you try to get next character via `getc(fp)` that is enough to cause the crash . `fp` will be invalid pointer at that moment.

Also, I see no restrictions for crossing `data` boundary:

```
    pString->data[count] = getc(fp);
    count++;  // count is not restricted from growing
```

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean when you say "I see no restrictions for crossing data boundary?" Also, how would I go about increasing the capacity of pString->data without the free? When I assign the value of t_data to pString->data, does that not solve the issue of using freed memory?

Comment: I do not see check  `count <  pString->capacity * 2` to prevent `count` being increased beyond the allocated memory.

Comment: Added the restriction but still no luck. Any recommendations for pinpointing the cause of the segmentation fault?

Comment: I haven't worked with file pointers in a long time so I assumed I could just increment it to move to the next character in the file. I've now removed it. Would something like: while(getc(fp)) work to accomplish that?

Comment: "I could just increment it to move to the next character in the file."   - no you cannot do that.  `getc`  will  get you next char: `int ch = getc(fp); while (ch != EOF) { 
    ch = getc(fp);
  }`

Comment: This is kind of embarrassing but I just realized the segmentation fault was because I never made the text file that my function was supposed to extract from. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: @Billy I am afraid that that is not the only problem which you had... Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I also made sure to fix what you said about the file pointer.